# How do you affect the font-family in a page's window title?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I stumbled onto a Yahoo page and while looking at its tab title, I saw that it was Serif as apposed to my other tabs which are Sans-Serif.  I cannot figure out how this styling is happening.

[This is the page with the strange tab title font-family](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/aria-role-application-53608.html)

[image: Image showing the tab as well as two other tabs with one title being manually set and the other with the title copy pasted]

If I change the title of the page itself with `document.title = "Something else";` the font-family changes to the same family that my other tabs have.  Copying and pasting the title into a different tab retains the Sans-Serif as well if I print it from `document.title`, copy it, and then use the clipboard data to set `document.title` of another tab.

Why is the font-family different for this tab?  Is it an encoding thing?  Additionally, this only seems to happen in Chrome.  The page has the normal tab font-family in Firefox.